# CSS transition/animation in GTK+. Is it possible?

Tags: css, gtk, css-animations, glade, opensuse

In the GTK+ documentation you can read that:

> CSS defines a mechanism by which changes in CSS property values can be made to take effect gradually, instead of all at once. GTK+ supports these transitions as well.

So I've been trying to run transitions in an application written in GTK since yesterday. Unfortunately, I did not even go one step further, because there is no reasonable example in the documentation. Could someone tell me how to run CSS transitions and animations in GTK application?

EDIT: 
This is a system problem. I ran a program on openSUSE Leap in a virtual machine and everything works. The question now is why it does not work on openSUSE Tumbleweed?
Here are examples I'm trying to run, but without any success.

```
@keyframes spin {
   to { -gtk-icon-transform: rotate(1turn); }
}

spinner {
   animation-name: spin;
   animation-duration: 1s;
   animation-timing-function: linear;
   animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

button {
  transition-property: width;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

button:hover {
  width: 300px;
}
```

here is glade file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.36.0 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.22"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="main_window">
    <property name="name">main_window</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkFixed" id="fixed">
        <property name="name">fixed</property>
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
            <property name="name">button</property>
            <property name="width_request">100</property>
            <property name="height_request">80</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">107</property>
            <property name="y">104</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="label">
            <property name="name">label</property>
            <property name="width_request">100</property>
            <property name="height_request">80</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">label</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">107</property>
            <property name="y">17</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkSpinner" id="spinner">
            <property name="name">spinner</property>
            <property name="width_request">100</property>
            <property name="height_request">80</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="active">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">107</property>
            <property name="y">196</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
    <child type="titlebar">
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

and main.c

```c
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

GtkBuilder *builder;

// The highest level
GObject *main_window;
GObject *fixed;

// fixed level
GObject *label;
GObject *button;
GObject *spinner;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
   builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file("../glade.glade");

   main_window = gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "main_window");
   fixed = gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "fixed");
   label = gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "label");
   button = gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "button");
   spinner = gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "spinner");

   // Build signal structure
   gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);
   g_signal_connect(main_window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

   // Prepare css file
   GtkCssProvider *provider = gtk_css_provider_new();
   gtk_css_provider_load_from_path(
       provider, "../css.css", NULL);
   gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen(
       gdk_display_get_default_screen(gdk_display_get_default()),
       GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(provider),
       GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);

   // Create window
   gtk_widget_show(GTK_WIDGET(main_window));
   gtk_main();

   return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: You need to show the widget tree you run this on, i.e. the C/Python/ui/whatever file... It won't do anything if you're not running it on the right widgets. Also ensure your GTK version is in accordance with the documentation; CSS used to be quite different in earlier versions of 3.x and the quoted syntax should only be reliably usable from about 3.20 onwards.

Comment: I added to main post all files I use. File tree is flat: main.c, glade.glade, css.css.

Comment: pkg-config --modversion gtk+-3.0 --> 3.24.20

Comment: I've just tested it correcting `min-with` property in Ubuntu 20.04 Mate Desktop. Button transition  doesn't work. `gtk+-3.0` version is `3.24.20`

Answer (score 2):

Check your console. When I build and run with these 3 files, I see this:

> `(a.exe:30940): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:10:50.844: Theme parsing error: test.css:20:7: 'width' is not a valid property name`.

You probably wanted `min-width`. That and the `Spinner` both animate just fine for me after fixing that by replacing both references to `width` in the CSS with `min-width`. I also checked that changing the spin animation duration has effect.

Comment: min-width, you're right, This is very strange, because the button is now bigger, but without any animation. And spinner is not turning. Maybe there are some settings, that have to be turned on?

My system: openSUSE Tumbleweed VERSION="20200612"

Comment: This is a 100% system problem. I ran a program on openSUSE Leap in a virtual machine and everything works. The question now is why it does not work on openSUSE Tumbleweed?

Comment: That seems like a question for the OpenSUSE team/tracker. It might be related to the VM and/or its settings, as I seem to recall that animations get disabled sometimes, but I think it's going to be the environment that makes that decision and not GTK or the code.